# Word/Excel CustomUI - controlling scaling policy

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, user-interface, ribbon

Is there any way to control the scaling policy in MS-CUSTOMUI for the MS Word (or Excel) ribbon, or otherwise force a control group to always display in 'collapsed' mode?

For instance, the following custom ribbon groups:

[image]

The first group is displayed in full, the other two are collapsed. Is there any way I can control this behavior in the Word UI, so I can choose what order the groups will be collapsed in, or force certain groups to be collapsed by default? I see that the [Windows Ribbon Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-templates), for instance, allows scaling policies to be set for each control group, or for each control group to be forced to a certain scale. Is there anything similar for MS-CUSTOMUI?

I know there are alternatives such as using the menu element to create a drop-menu, but these are all limited to using unsized buttons, whereas when the group is collapsed by the dynamic UI, the button size is retained.

Comment: Are you using the Customize the Ribbon "tool" in the user interface or are you doing direct XML editing? http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm ----- I assume the latter.

Comment: Direct XML editing - this is for a custom UI.